# How to set the number of "mappers"/partitions in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a doubt in some codes I have been reading. They referring "partitions" as "maps" (thinking as the `MapReduce` style) in the same way:

- `--total-executor-cores #maps` is the number of maps.
- `var data = sc.textFile(inputFile, nPartitions)` The code comment says "`nPartitions` is the number of the maps"

So, conceptually, are they the same?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct.
the number of cores is mapped to the number of tasks that you can compute in ||.
this number is fixed. But the number of partitions varies along the job. for each partiton, we have a task and a task is processed by a core. 
The number of partitions defines the number of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to control specific partitioning of an RDD you can use "[repartition](http://[https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#repartition(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)])" method or "[coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)" method. 
If you want to be have it on all rdds for all mappers you should use: 
sparkConf.set("[spark.default.parallelism](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)", s"${numbers of mappers you want}")
If you want to controll the shuffle (reducers) 
sparkConf.set("[spark.sql.shuffle.partitions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)", s"${numbers of reducers you want}")

Number of cores is the number of cores you assign to job in a cluster.